# Migrating from TestFlight to Apple's TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

My team has been using TestFlight for the past few months to beta test new releases. I got an email today about Apple's integrated version of TestFlight [1](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/).

What's the best way to transition my users to the new version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

New testflight platform, included in iTunes Connect, is quiet different than the old platform.
There aren't methods to automatically move your build and users to new TestFlight.

New TestFlight manages two types of tester: internal and external. These two types are self-explained and you have to configure every user that you has on old platform. You will configure the users through mail, up to 1000.

The builds you would to test, must to be uploaded via classic method for submitting apps. At this point, after a couple of minutes, you can enable the build for testing.
Apple have to review the build before enabling it; in a couple of hours (late, 1 day) you will have the new build to distribute.

Finally, when build is available, you can distribute it via iTunes Connect prerelease pane: users will receive mail with link for download automatically app on the device. No more UUID specification needed.

Check the documentation at the following link: [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)

I hope this may help you.